# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - navbar-right issue in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created two dropdown using `navbar-right`.

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PYda4/) for it.

Issue is... It is working fine in desktop and large screens.

If I resize the browser window. The dropdown gets in a list view with the entire width of the screen when re-sized.

Re-size the result window and you'll come to know my problem.

Help me to overcome this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really the way to use a Bootstrap `navbar`.  The idea of the `navbar` is that it collapses down on mobile, which is what you're seeing happening here.  Except, in the Bootstrap `navbar`, [you are supposed to put some containers with specific class names](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and a `<button>` etc.  You're code just seems to be using `navbar-right` for the sake of floating it right.

Try this instead.  It's 1 list, each `<li>` has a dropdown.  There's no `navbar` classes.  Note that I've added the class `nav`.  This just gives the `<a>` some padding and colouring on hover etc.  You can remove that class and style as required.  I also added the class 'pull-right' which is Bootstrap's helper class for floating right.

```
<div>
    <ul class="pull-right nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Some CSS

```
div > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
```

This won't be responsive like the `navbar`, but that seemed to be the problem in the first place.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/PYda4/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was confused in these bootstrap classes. Now I'm very clear. Thanks again +1. :)